# Hard problems book in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, big-list, book-recommendation

Could you suggest me a book where I can find **hard** problems in Linear Algebra for an undergraduate student? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hoffman and Kunze have pretty hard questions in the later chapters. Depends on what level of linear algebra you are interested in.

Comment: perhaps it is time to consider graduate level as Steven Roman's "*Advanced Linear Algebra*" book

Answer (score 5):

Some of them are quite advanced:

1. Richard Bellman, *Introduction to Matrix Analysis*, McGraw-Hill, 1960.
2. Felix R. Gantmacher, *Theory of Matrices*, vol. I & II, Chelsea, 1960.
3. Kenneth M. Hoffman and Ray A. Kunze, *Linear Algebra*, Pearson, 1971.
4. Peter D. Lax, *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, Wiley, 2007.
5. Thomas Muir, *Treatise on the Theory of Determinants*, Longman, Green & Co., 1933.
6. Gilbert Strang, *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, 4th edition, Academic Press, 2009.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, one reference is Friedberg et al, Linear Algebra Four Edition.
Other reference is Putnam and Beyond from Titu Andreecu in the section of Linear Algebra, it have really challenging problems.